# How to enable pipe mode for XGBoost BYO script distributed training on parquet data using SageMaker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, xgboost, amazon-sagemaker

If I use BYO (bring your own) script of XGBoost with distributed training and Pipe input mode on parquet data using SageMaker, what change is needed from a distributed training code (it works with script mode on parquet data) to enable pipe mode?

NOTE: If I change `input_mode` to `Pipe`, no model output is uploaded into s3 even if the training step has been completed. However, there are warning messages such as `WARNING:root:Host algo-2 not being used for distributed training.` and `WARNING:root:Host algo-1 not being used for distributed training.`

Can anyone help with this?